# Como inserir style em um elemento Zend_Form_Element_Select?

Tags: php, zend, formulário, html-option

Como posso inserir um `style` em um elemento `option` utilizando Zend_Form?

Estou utilizando **Zend Framework 1**.

Comment: Pelo que se vê na [documentação do `Zend_Form_Element_Select`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.9/Zend_Form/Element/Zend_Form_Element_Select.html), isso não deve ser possível diretamente. É provável você precise montar suas opções na unha (quem sabe estendendo uma classe do Zend, como sugerido (em inglês) aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012943/how-could-i-add-attributes-to-option-tags-using-zend-framework)

Comment: Lembrando que somente alguns browsers suportam estilos em options.

Comment: Boa observação...

Comment: Por favor, poste o código que gera esses elementos para que eu busque uma solução melhor...

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o `setAttrib` para inserir seu atributo e o valor:

```php
foreach ($this->getElements() as $element) {
      $element->setAttrib('class', $minhaClasse);
}
```

Mais sobre, [aqui.](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.elements.html)

Comment: Kenny, para cada option será atribuída uma cor diferente que virá de uma sql, neste teu exemplo, colocando em um foreach no momento da inserção do option, vai funcionar?

Comment: Sim, editei a resposta de como você pode fazer!

Comment: Kenny, para esta tua solução a classe é inserida no elemento select e não no option. :( o que preciso é uma alternativa para colorir cada option com cores diferentes, talvez até inserir um span dentro do option com o style ou class devida.